# How to send and append new context variable to Watson Assistant skills via V1 API using python?

Tags: python, watson-assistant

We have made a bot using numeric data and are now testing the possibility to enhance the system by using python V1 API to further analyze the data. Python results should then be send back to skills to further use and improve the bot.

Python code discusses well with skills, giving the right context and context can be updated as well in python code.

We just can't get how to send/update new context with new variables back to skills. How to see it appended in skills context variable list?

Comment: Please [edit] to add meaningful code and a problem description here. Posting a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `context` of Watson Assistant is stored in `JSON` format. The request or response (in `v1 API`) contain `context` field. E.g.

```
"context" : {
  "system" : { ... system stuff, do not touch},
  "variable1" : "value1",
  "my_array" : ["one", "two", "three"]
}
```

So only thing one must do in order to add a new variable to the context or to change value of a variable in the context one needs to modify this `context` field.